# Best way to add tabs within android app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm thinking of adding tabs to my android app. Currently, I am using the same activity and adding the appropriate fragments based on the tabs selected. I was wondering if that's a good way, or should I add an activity per tab and then within the individual activity, have fragments as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on right track. Have one [Fragment Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) and attach all the fragments to that activity.